# Python - Plot with pcolormesh and basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to plot my data for instance with a stereographic projection. However, when I try to plot, nothing is plotted except the continents.

To explain, this is a figure of my data plot as :

```
plt.pcolormesh(longrid_t, latgrid_t,totvart_t)
```

where `longrid_t` is the longitude, `latgrid_t` is the latitude and `totvart_t` is the data that I would like to plot.

Here is the figure plotted only with pcolormesh (without basemap) as `plt.pcolormesh(longrid_t, latgrid_t,totvart_t)`:

[image: Figure plotted only with pcolormesh (without basemap : plt.pcolormesh(longrid_t, latgrid_t,totvart_t)]

Now, I tried to plot these data using a stereographic projection :

```
map = Basemap(width=10000000,height=6000000, resolution='l',projection='stere',
        lat_0=40.,lon_0=-40.)
map.fillcontinents(color='darkgrey',lake_color='darkgrey')
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawparallels(arange(-90, 91., 10.), labels=[1, 0, 0, 1],
                dashes=[1, 1], linewidth=0.25, color='0.5')
map.drawmeridians(arange(-180., 181., 10.), labels=[1, 0, 0, 1],
                dashes=[1, 1], linewidth=0.25, color='0.5')

map.pcolormesh(longrid_t, latgrid_t, totvart_t, cmap='jet')
map.colorbar()
```

However, the result with this stereographic projection is not what I expected:

[image: stereographic projection]

I have tried also with other projections. And also with pcolor and contourf instead of pcolormesh. But it gives me the same result.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried using the `latlon=True` kwarg in your call to `map.pcolormesh`?

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert your coordinate data to projection xy coordinates and then plot with converted coordinates:

```
map = Basemap(width=10000000,height=6000000, resolution='l',projection='stere',
        lat_0=40.,lon_0=-40.)
map.fillcontinents(color='darkgrey',lake_color='darkgrey')
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawparallels(arange(-90, 91., 10.), labels=[1, 0, 0, 1],
                dashes=[1, 1], linewidth=0.25, color='0.5')
map.drawmeridians(arange(-180., 181., 10.), labels=[1, 0, 0, 1],
                dashes=[1, 1], linewidth=0.25, color='0.5')
# convert lat-lon to projection coordinate system
xpt,ypt = m(longrid_t, latgrid_t) # convert to projection map

map.pcolormesh(xpt, ypt, totvart_t, cmap='jet')
map.colorbar()
```

Answer (score 0):

It works adding `latlon=True` kwarg to my call to `map.pcolormesh`

thus

```
map.pcolormesh(longrid_t, latgrid_t, totvart_t, cmap='jet',latlon=True)
```